# Catch 22: Load Script if Element That Depends on Script Exists

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to load javascript in the `<head>` only if a certain element exists in the `<body>`.

However, I have a problem: I am loading a Web Component, which is just a `<script>` hosted elsewhere and is pulled in as:

```
<script src="https://someurl.com/some-web-component.min.js"></script>
```

This web component file is huge, so I don't want to pull it in *unless* it is inserted into body by our Content Management System (CMS).

The constraints I am working under are:

• The `<head>` is shared between pages, so I need conditional logic

• I have no control over the `<body>` inserted by the CMS, which will potentially contain the `<my-web-component>` tag

• I NEED the script to load the web component, so I can't use jQuery's $(document).ready, at least I think I can't - an error will be thrown because the browser won't know the element exists

This plunker partially shows my problem, minus all the web component complexity:

https://plnkr.co/edit/GGif2RNHX1iLAvSk1nUw?utm_source=next&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next&p=preview

Any way around this?

Comment: What does that script do? Does any other script depends on it, or it depends on anything? Is this a library? Any inline script in body uses it?

Comment: The script defines the custom element, which is html/javascript which pulls in the form.io library and data from an API and then displays it to the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading.

In this case you can look for the Component and add the script with something like the following

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  if(document.querySelector('Component')){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://someurl.com/some-web-component.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(script)
  }
});
```

Probably a better approach though would be to add the `script` in the head with `async` attribute and later remove it if the component is not found.
Something like this

```
<script async src = "https://someurl.com/some-web-component.min.js"> </script> 
<script >
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    if (document.querySelector('Component') == null) {
      var script = document.querySelector('script[src="https://someurl.com/some-web-component.min.js"]')
      document.head.removeChild(script)
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

More about [DOM lifecycle events](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded)
More about [async script loading](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/building-the-dom-faster-speculative-parsing-async-defer-and-preload/)

Comment: This does seem to work, thank you. Testing in detail now. I still don't understand this: "The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading." - what does 'parsed' mean here?

Comment: @VSO, it means all the elements have been rendered in short. Which means your `querySelector` will be able to find the tag you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

I am using `$(document).ready` and inside this method checking if element exists or not. It is working completely fine for me. Below is code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery Test Element Exists or Not</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var elem = document.querySelector('h1');
      var isElemPresent = !!elem;
      console.log('Is the element present: ', isElemPresent);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

  <script>
    var elem = document.querySelector('h1');
    var isElemPresent = !!elem;
    console.log('Oh NOW it works...: ', isElemPresent);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not sure where you are facing issue while using jQuery. There might be some other issue. Above approach is good enough to load script after checking if element is present.

Plunker link: 
https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cjgczwlzt000knneldv5d52ea/

Comment: The example is limited. I mentioned in the question that I need to load a custom html element / tag. Document ready will fail, because the script won't be available to define the tag.